# How to check value assigned to "string"

Tags: r

So I have list with strings (IDs) but in the same time my strings are names of the values and some of these values are just NULL. Is there way to run a loop which will check if there is value behind name or it's just NULL?

```
>list <- c("id1","id2","id3")
>id1
dimension5 sessions
        12        2
>id2
dimension5 sessions
        13        4
>id3
NULL
```

As final result I would like to see something like this (or 1 instead of yes and 0 instead of no)

```
id  value
id1   yes
id2   yes
id3    no
```

Comment: @RichardScriven - presumably it is as it would return `"Error: object 'id3' not found"` if it didn't even exist.

Comment: @RichardScriven yes, because it's result of pulling report from Google Analytics. That guy didn't accomplish my condition so NULL was assigned to him.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`get` or `mget` each item and check if it `is.null`:

```
L <- c("id1","id2","id3")
id1 <- c(12,2)
id2 <- c(13,4)
id3 <- NULL

stack(!vapply(mget(L), is.null, logical(1)))
#  values ind
#1   TRUE id1
#2   TRUE id2
#3  FALSE id3
```

Comment: You could also use `NA` in place of `logical(1)` because it's logical too and because Fore!

Comment: @RichardScriven - if we're code-golfing, i'd just use `stack(!sapply(mget(L), is.null))` but I keep forcing myself to use `vapply` when the output format is known.

Comment: @AlienDeg - trying to reduce the number of characters in code to an absolute minimum. Richard's suggestion was to shave off a few letters by replacing `logical(1)` with `NA`